# New order notification mail not working in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email

My website is on one server.and mail is on different server.

My website is in Magento 1.9.2.3. It is now live on server and the order comes as the URL is same as old website.

But the problem is Mail has to be sent on new order to admin and customer too. **Mail functionality is not working.**

I have set 
`System -> Configuration -> Store Email Address. and System -> Configuration -> sales -> Sales Emails`

I have also set `System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Cron(Schedule Task)`

**Still i don't receive any mail on new order [On admin side or as a customer]**

I have also following steps which are in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqRlXmBvvkE

I have also look that blog
[image]

Comment: Is your cornjob working properly??

Comment: How to check that? My website is on server now.Please provide me steps to check cronjob.

Comment: Have you tried to send test mail via root ??

Comment: New order mail is sent by cronjob in latest magento version.so you need to configure cron job on server

Comment: https://blog.nexcess.net/2010/10/03/finding-the-status-of-magento-cron-jobs-tasks/ This link will help you check your cornjob status

Comment: i have add a new cronjob by cpanel -> advanced -> cron job -> Add new cron job. I have configured admin -> sustem -> configuration ->system-> cron. What the other task i should do?

Comment: install [AOE Scheduler](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html) extension

Comment: It allows for troubleshooting of long-running magento cron jobs, and easily accessing a list of your magento cron jobs

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Magento after version 1.9.1 depend on cron to send order mail. Try install AOE Scheduler, https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html
With this module you can if your cron is working or not. If not enable it by adding php /home//public_html/cron.php 
This is only example, try to point to your website directory.

Answer (score 0):

check your cronjob working or not??

You can add this to cron.sh after the INSTALLDIR variable is set:

```
# absolute path to magento installation
INSTALLDIR=`echo $0 | sed 's/cron\.sh//g'`
date >> "$0".log
whoami  >> "$0".log
```

And this to cron.php after the dispatchEvent call:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
$log = fopen(__FILE__.'.log', 'a');
fwrite($log, date("Y-m-d H:i:s").PHP_EOL);
fclose($log);
```

After 6 minutes you should see both these files in Magento's directory if cron is running.

```
./cron.php.log
./cron.sh.log
```

If you have tried everything and still cant get cron to work, perhaps this unsupported workaround might help. Adding the following to the top of index.php will cause cron to run in the background whenever someone accesses your website.

```
<?php
$pathToCron = dirname(__FILE__)."/cron.sh";
exec( "sh $pathToCron > /dev/null &" );
Another workaround

*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget http://your_webpage.com/cron.php
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i have added code in both the files.But no any log file is created in magento directory.Any other solution?

Comment: Its means your cron job is not working.  can you tell me your cron setting??

Comment: Yes but what do you want to know exactly ? & where is the cron setting located ?

Comment: go with this path : system->config->advance->system->cron. here you can see cron setting

Comment: Generate Schedules Every :  1   ,  Schedule Ahead for
:1   ,    Missed if Not Run Within
:15 ,    History Cleanup Every
:120,   Success History Lifetime
: 120,   Failure History Lifetime
:120

Comment: check here : System > Configuration > Sales Emails and make sure that Enabled is set to Yes.

Comment: all other mail are ok or not??

Comment: Mail is not working of any type. Can you please tell me what should i write System -> Configuration -> System -> mail Sending Setting ?

Comment: Disable Email Communications- > No, Host-> your mail hosting server like(smtp.gmail.com), Port (25) -> 465 for gmail, Set Return-Path -> NO

Comment: add me on skype : ajay.surtikart or maitri.infosys

Comment: Can you help me via team viewer?

Comment: I am available after 8:00 PM. currently its company time.

Comment: Ajay can you solve this? i added you on skype